# update a swift realm object through a view

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

in a Real Swift project I want to update a Realm object by a View. Thereby the Realm object is a class, I only want to communicate via methods. My view looks like this:

```
struct ViewBook: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var book: Book
    @State var text: String

    init(book: Book){
        self.book = book
        self.text = ""
    }

    func nextPage(){    
            let realm = book.thaw()!.realm!
            
            let thawedBook = self.book.thaw()!
            try! realm.write{
                self.text = thawedBook.getNextChapter()
    }
}
```

This uses a book object, which is stored in the database and looks like this.

```
class Book: Object ,ObjectKeyIdentifiable ,Identifiable, Codable{
    @Persisted var chapterList: SpeedReader.chapterList?

    func getNextChapter() -> String{
        self.text = chapterList!.getNextChapter()
        return text
    }
}
```

```
class chapterList: Object, Codable{
    @Persisted var _list: RealmSwift.List<chapter>
    @Persisted var _currentChapter: chapter? = chapter()
    @Persisted var _indexChapter = 0

    func getNextChapter() -> String {
        do {
            let realm = self.realm!.thaw()
            try realm.write{
                self.thaw()?._indexChapter += 1
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error in Chapterlist", error)
        }
        
        return self._list[_indexChapter].getText()
    }
}
```

```
class chapter: Object, Codable{
    @Persisted var htmlString = ""

    func getText() -> String{
        return self.htmlString
    }
}
```

my idea is to click on a button in the view, which updates the book and the chapterList and at the end returns the new text to the view.

with my current code i get the error

```
[General] The Realm is already in a write transaction
```

and I don't know if this helps, with some alternative code, which I unfortunately didn't save, I get the errors

```
[General] Attempting to modify a frozen object - call thaw on the Object instance first.
```

and

```
[General] Can't perform transactions on a frozen realm
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's why the error occurs

When `nextPage` is called, it opens a write transaction

```
func nextPage(){
   try! realm.write {
      self.text = thawedBook.getNextChapter()
```

within the write, `.getNextChapter` is called on the (Book) `thawedBook`

```
class Book: Object ,ObjectKeyIdentifiable ,Identifiable, Codable{
    func getNextChapter() -> String{
       self.text = chapterList!.getNextChapter()
```

which calls `.getNextChapter` on the `chapterList` object

```
class chapterList: Object, Codable{
   func getNextChapter() -> String {
      do {
         let realm = self.realm!.thaw()
         try realm.write{
             self.thaw()?._indexChapter += 1
```

which attempts to open another write transaction, hence the error.

I am not seeing any reason to open a write within `nextPage` so removing that will fix that particular issue.

A few (hopefully helpful) observations;

1. In general a Book has Chapters which could be represented by two objects - the code also implements an intermediary object `chapterList` which doesn't seem to serve a purpose. My suggestion is to make chapters a `List` property of the book which will be easier to manage; update query etc. Also, the currentChapter or page could also be a property of the book.
2. There's a lot of thawing going on which is inherently hard to manage. One option is to use implicit writes since Book is an @ObservedRealmObject see [Quick Writes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#perform-a-quick-write)
3. Best practice in coding is to capitalize Classes, Structs and Enums which makes reading and understanding the code much more clear as there's a visible indicator to differentiate a Class from a var (which should always be lowercase)

> ```
> class ChapterList: Object, Codable {
>    ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed the write transaction from next page.
However, I still get the error "[General] Attempting to modify a frozen object - call thaw on the Object instance first."
When debugging I came across that in "getNextChapter" from "ChapterList" it goes into the write block, but apparently terminates at "thaw()?".

Comment: @Martin01 I think it's just the placement. Thaw the object first, then perform the write. *If you pass an object you are observing with @ObservedRealmObject or @ObservedResults into a function where you perform an explicit write transaction that modifies the object, you must thaw it first.*. See the code example here [Perform an explicit write](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#perform-an-explicit-write). See the realm and `thisEmployee` is thawed before the write.